RavenDB specify Lucene vs Corax in C# code
I'm migrating from RavenDB 6.0.106 to 6.2.
I have a lot of complex indexes that are not compatible with Corax.
Using the UI, one can set which index type is used.
However, after perusing the RavenDB site, I have yet to find how to specify this in C# code alone. Is this even possible? If so, how is it done? Where's the documentation?

You can specify which search engine to use in 3 ways/levels:

Setting the search engine server-wide (for all databases):
update your settings.json file as shown in this link: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/6.2/csharp/indexes/search-engine/corax#select-search-engine-server-wide
Setting the search engine per database:
done via the Studio as shown in this link:
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/6.2/csharp/indexes/search-engine/corax#select-search-engine-per-database
Setting the search engine per index:
can be done via the client API code as shown in this link:
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/6.2/csharp/indexes/search-engine/corax#select-index-search-engine-using-code
For example, set this in your index definition:
 SearchEngineType = Raven.Client.Documents.Indexes.SearchEngineType.Corax;
Or
 SearchEngineType = Raven.Client.Documents.Indexes.SearchEngineType.Lucene;

